# Dynamic CRM- Showing "Error" instead of "view properties" in definition of a process

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

In **definition** of some of the CRM processes (ex., Action or workflow), where we as usual see steps of the workflow with properties button following them, recently we have seen the this problem:

In the **UPDATE** step, instead of showing "view properties" or "set properties", it shows the word "error".

Also, note that the user has read & write access to the entity which is being updated.
Also, we see this problem in both activate and deactivate states.

Comment: Is this for every WF or some particular WF, in all environments or particular sandbox ? Can you see the exported solution.xml for abnormalities ?

Comment: Thanks Arun for your response. The problem has been solved, but to me the solution was not logical at all. By removing the access to that entity and adding Read & Write access again, the user could see the properties of the update step.